Must $V$ have codimension 1 in a dense subspace if its closure is codimension 1 in the whole space?
Let $H$ be a (real) Hilbert space and $V\subset U\subset H$ where $U$ is dense proper subspace of $H$ and $V$ is a proper subspace of $U$. It is given that the closure of $V$, $\overline{V}$ has codimension 1 in $H$, denote $V^{\perp}=<v>$. Can we conclude that $V$ has codimension 1 in $U$?
Here is my reasoning. Let $(U, ||.||)$ be a normed space with the norm induced from $H$. Assume $V$ is not codimension 1 in $U$, then there exists $\phi_{1},\phi_{2},...\in U^{*}$ such that $V=\cap_{i}ker(\phi_{i})$ ($U^{*}$ is the dual space of $U$). Now $U^{*}=H$ since $U$ is dense in $H$, this means there exists linear independent $v_{1}, v_{2},...\in H$ such that $\langle v_{i}, V\rangle=0$ for all $i$ with $\phi_{i}(.)=\langle v_{i},.\rangle$. But only $\langle v, V\rangle=0$, contradiction. So $V$ must have codimension 1 in $U$.
Edit: The fact that $\overline{V}$ has codimension 1 is actually an assumption. So if the statement is inconsistent, that may be the assumption is wrong.

No. Let $H = \ell^2$, $U = \text{span}\{e_n\}_{n \geq 1} + \mathbb{R}x$, where $x$ is any vector in $H$ but not in $\text{span}\{e_n\}_{n \geq 1}$, and $V = \text{span}\{e_n\}_{n \geq 2}$. Then indeed $\overline{V}$ is of co-dimension $1$ in $H$ as $V^\perp = \mathbb{R}e_1$ but $V$ is of co-dimension $2$ in $U$. (In fact, by adding more vectors to $U$ like this, you can make $V$ have arbitrary co-dimension larger than or equal to $1$ and smaller than or equal to continuum in $U$.)

The problem with your proof, really, is continuity - you never assumed $V$ is closed in $U$, so your $\phi_i$ may not be bounded.

Thank you for the counterexample. But I still don't understand that why $V$ closed in $U$ will guarantee $\phi_{i}$ are bounded.

@Ken.Wong Well, first, if $V$ is not closed in $U$ this will never work. Indeed, if all $\phi_i$ are bounded, then $V = \bigcap_i \text{ker}(\phi_i)$ is easily seen to be closed. For the converse, if $V$ is closed in $U$, which is normed, then it is a standard fact that the quotient space $U/V$ is normed itself, under the quotient norm $|x+V| = \inf_{y \in x+V} |y|$. And under the quotient norm the quotient map $\pi: U \to U/V$ is bounded (in fact, even contractive). So if $V$ is of co-dimension at least $n$ in $U$, then $U/V$ has dimension at least $n$. As it is normed, by Hahn-Banach…

… you can choose $n$ linearly independent bounded linear functionals $\psi_i$ on $U/V$. Then $\phi_i = \psi_i \circ \pi$ are linearly independent and bounded, so you can now proceed further with your argument and show that if $V \subset U$ is closed and $U \subset H$ is dense, then $V$ is of co-dimension at least $n$ in $U$ implies $\overline{V}$ is of co-dimension at least $n$ in $H$. (In fact, you don’t even need $H$ to be a Hilbert space, just that it is a normed space is enough.)

Thank you for your detailed response. I assume that if $V$ is closed in $U$, then my argument is fine.

@Ken.Wong Indeed, that is the case.
